# A consideration on the last Maxwell equations: doubt

Tags: electromagnetism, maxwell-equations

If I consider the last equation of Maxwell,

$$\oint_\gamma \mathbf{B}\cdot d\boldsymbol{\ell}=\mu_0\left(I_C+\epsilon_0\frac{d\Phi(\mathbf{E})}{dt}\right) \tag 1$$

where $I_C$ indicates the conduction current generated by a potential difference, and $I_S$ it is the displacement current

$$I_S=\epsilon_0\frac{d\Phi(\mathbf{E})}{dt}$$

if I don't have sources the $(1)$ becomes:

$$\oint_\gamma \mathbf{B}\cdot d\boldsymbol{\ell}=\mu_0\epsilon_0\frac{d\Phi(\mathbf{E})}{dt}\tag 2$$

Is this term provided by the right side of the $(2)$ is due to the fact that even if I don't have a potential difference the charges in a wire always move in any direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When interpreting Maxwell's last equation
$$\oint_\gamma \mathbf{B}\cdot d\boldsymbol{\ell}=\mu_0\left(I_C+\epsilon_0\frac{d\Phi(\mathbf{E})}{dt}\right) \tag 1$$
there is no need to bring potential difference into the game.
<sub>Actually the concept of electric potential, which is so important
in electrostatics, is of limited use in electrodynamics.
As said in [Electric_potential - Generalization to electrodynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_potential#Generalization_to_electrodynamics):
*When time-varying magnetic fields are present (...),
it is not possible to describe the electric field simply in terms of a scalar potential $V$
because the electric field is no longer conservative.*</sub>

$I_C$ is the conduction current (i.e. moving charges)
regardless why the charges are moving.
This current creates a magnetic field $\mathbf{B}$ wrapping around it.

The second term on the right side
$\left(\epsilon_0\frac{d\Phi(\mathbf{E})}{dt}\right)$
is due to an electric field $\mathbf{E}$ which changes with time $t$
regardless where this electric field comes from.
It has nothing to do with charges
(even though its unit is also Ampère like it is for $I_C$).
This changing electric field also creates a magnetic field $\mathbf{B}$
wrapping around it.

Comment: Thank you very much also for your answer that I have appreciated (see also the comment to the previous user).

Comment: Why is there a downvote? What is the reason?

Answer (score 1):

"Is this term provided by the right side of the (2) [is] due to the fact that even if I don't have a potential difference the charges in a wire always move in any direction?"

I think you have a misunderstanding. Your last equation needs no wire. It works everywhere, including in a vacuum.

The equation is an integrated form of the Maxwell equation itself, which, leaving out the source term, is
$$\text {curl} \vec B = \mu_0 \epsilon_0 \frac{\partial \vec E}{dt}\ \ \ \text{that is}\ \ \  \nabla \times \vec B=\mu_0 \epsilon_0 \frac{\partial \vec E}{dt}$$
Some people think of this as telling you that a changing electric field acts like moving electric charges and generates a magnetic field around it. I prefer to think of the equation as relating two aspects of the electromagnetic field at a point, $\vec B$ and $\vec E$.

Comment: Meanwhile thank you very much for your explanation that I have understood well. Perfect. I give the check mark to the user Thomas because he has fewer votes than you, but I'm always for honesty and kindness.

Comment: Why is there a downvote? What is the reason?